# Concentration inequality to bound expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, expected-value

Let $X$ be a non-negative r.v. so that 
$$ P(X \geq t) \leq C \exp\bigg\{\frac{-t^2/2}{\sigma^2 + bt}\bigg\}$$
for positive $\sigma, b$ and $C\geq 1$. Show that

$$ E[X] \leq 2\sigma (\sqrt{\pi} + \sqrt{\log C}) + 4b(1 + \log C) $$

I know how to usually get concentration bound or bound the deviation from the mean, but no idea how to bound this expectation here. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Isn't something like $\int_\Omega X d\mathbb{P} = \int_0^\infty P(X \ge t)dt$ true?

Comment: Are you suggesting a brute force integration will get the result? Thanks!

Comment: But the integral seems impossible to compute... Thanks!

Comment: yea, so try bounding it from above by something you can integrate

Comment: also, $\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2} dt = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$

Comment: \begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{t^2}{2(\sigma^2+bt)}\right)dt \le \int_0^{\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{t^2}{4\max\{\sigma^2,bt\}}\right)dt.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you everyone for the comments! But I still struggle with getting the exact bound, e.g. shouldn't C be moved outside, how do we even get log(C)? I would really appreciate if you write a more detailed answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hold on, this inequality doesn't appear true. Let's take $C = 100, \sigma^2 = 1, b = 10^{-6}$ and suppose the tail-bound were exact. [Then](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=100%5Cint_0%5E%5Cinfty%20%5Cexp%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B-t%5E2%7D%7B2(1%20%2B%2010%5E%7B-6%7Dt)%7D%5Cright)dt)
\begin{align*}
E[X] = 100\int_0^\infty \exp\left(\frac{-t^2}{2(1 + 10^{-6}t)}\right)dt \approx 125.33
\end{align*}
[Yet](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5Ccdot1(%5Csqrt%7B%5Cpi%7D%2B%5Csqrt%7B%5Clog%20100%7D)%20%2B%204%5Ccdot%2010%5E%7B-6%7D%5Ccdot(1%2B%5Clog%20100))
\begin{align*}
2\cdot 1 \cdot (\sqrt{\pi}+\sqrt{\log 100}) + 4\cdot 10^{-6}\cdot(1+\log 100) \approx 7.84
\end{align*}

Comment: Maybe because the inequality for the probability is not tight everywhere?

Comment: That may be the case for some distributions, but setting a distribution to have that tight bound is a valid distribution, and for that distribution, it doesn't satisfy the inequality. We can then come up with an infinite number of other distributions which are arbitrarily close to that bound and still not satisfy the inequality.

Comment: This is actually Bernstein's inequality so it indeed holds? But I'm not sure how to prove it...

Comment: Thanks, I almost tried to apply OP's inequality to my work without verifying...